# Can a child be called from a parent in an inheritance relationship?

Tags: python, inheritance, composition

I have a circular dependency between two classes, a Parent and Child class in an inheritance relationship.  The Child obviously requires the Parent, but in this case the Parent also needs to call a specific Child.

Because the Parent and Child are stored in two different files, they have to require each other, which creates a circular dependency.  I realize that this is a bad practice but am not sure how to get around it.

Below is a small example which is similar to what I am doing.  In this case Animal is the Parent and Tiger is one child.

```
    class Animal:
       def can_beat_tiger(self):
         return not Tiger().can_eat(self)

    class Tiger(Animal):
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Some options include:

- Use composition.  Perhaps having a smaller Animal class that contains a self.specific_animal instance.
- Removing the child reference function from the parent and copying into each child.  In this case it would mean moving the can_beat_tiger() function to each child Animal.
- Dealing with it by having relative module imports. (a circular dependency)

Comment: In what's based the result of `can_beat_tiger()`?

Comment: Why can't you store the classes in the same file?

Comment: Christian - in this case can_beat_tiger() is a boolean, True or False.  

jwodder - I technically can, but would be afraid that it may still be an undesirable code smell.  Plus it would be a frustrating restriction as the codebase expands.

Comment: You are right about code smell. This situation is a clue that your design is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve this with overrides.  The base class would define a `can_beat` function, which always returns `False`.  Let the child class *fight* over it.  I don't think this is really ideal either, since the child classes need to be aware of each other.  You could also include a *master* function called `fight` which took two objects and calculated the result based on whatever criteria you decided was appropriate.  This would still need to include all possible child classes, however.

animal.py:

```
class Animal(object):
    def can_beat(self, other):
        return False
```

mouse.py:

```
import animal
import tiger


class Mouse(animal.Animal):
    def can_beat(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, tiger.Tiger):
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

tiger.py:

```
import animal
import mouse


class Tiger(animal.Animal):
    def can_beat(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Tiger):
            return False
        elif isinstance(other, mouse.Mouse):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

test.py:

```
from mouse import Mouse
from tiger import Tiger

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = Mouse()
    t = Tiger()
    print m.can_beat(t)
    print t.can_beat(m)
```

**NOTE**: You can generally solve ciruclar reference import by *not* using `from x import y`.  Doing so causes Python to compile the object, which causes lots of issues.  You can get around that by using `import x`.